# Remove the last word into the suffix if it matches II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, ESQ, JR, SR

Tags: java, regex

i have to do something like this : For the first name field, if the field consists of two or more words, remove the last word into the suffix field if the last word consists of one of the following: II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, ESQ, JR, SR .  I have tried with java pattern matching my code is :`String fName="shaik II .SR ,;

```
    String suffix=null;
    String [] genSuffixFname=fName.split(" ");


    if(genSuffixFname.length>=2){
        String line=genSuffixFname[genSuffixFname.length-1];
        String pattern="( II| III| IV| V| VI| VII| VIII| ESQ|.JR|.SR)";

        Pattern r =Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m=r.matcher(line);
        //System.out.println(m.find());
        if(m.find()){
            suffix=genSuffixFname[genSuffixFname.length-1];
        }                   
    }`
```

my suffix output is null. Any modifications to be done or any other ways i can get this>

Comment: When I run this snippet I get `suffix=".SR"`. Is this not the intended output?

Comment: If i give II or III as suffix its not working i am getting as null , its working though for >JR or .SR. I want it for all II| III| IV| V| VI| VII| VIII| ESQ|.JR|.SR

Comment: i think ` II| III| IV| V| VI| VII| VIII| ESQ` are preceded by single space. that's why it's not matching. And line may contain this without space.

Comment: Thats correct Muhammad imran, its working now thanks

Comment: In the above code variable, line i want  as a regular expression ? is it possible , for now its only taking the last word. I want to match any where in the complete name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test if a given string exists in another you can use [String#contains(anotherString)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Or use this code, which finds all matching by the given pattern :

```
String fName = "shaik II .SR IV";
String[] genSuffixFname = fName.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(genSuffixFname.length);

if (genSuffixFname.length >= 2) {
    String line = fName; 
    String pattern = "(II)|(III)|(IV)|(V)|(VI)|"
                + "(VII)|(VIII)|(ESQ)|(.JR)|(.SR)";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line); 
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}`
```

For more informations about regular expressions in Java:  [Read here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Spaces from the Pattern:
String pattern = "(II|III|IV|V|VI|VII|VIII|ESQ|.JR|.SR)";

Comment: In the above code variable, line i want  as a regular expression ? is it possible , for now its only taking the last word. I want to match any where in the complete name.

Comment: You mean the line with split ? To split on whitespaces you should use `fName.split("\\s");` for splitting on one whitespace. For splitting on more than one whitespace `fName.split("\\s+");` .. if this is not the answer to your question please ask once again :)

Comment: No , i meant String line=genSuffixFname[genSuffixFname.length-1]. This will match only if it appears at last, but i want it to match any where in the complete name.